# How to scan a big mysql table in parallel?

Tags: mysql, sqoop, full-table-scan

Suppose we have a big mysql table, which has less than 10 million rows.

If I want to select all the results, obviously a full table scan works fine.

```
select * from table_name;
```

But how to make it in parallel? I found the solution in Sqoop is `Split`.

```
select * from table_name where id >= 1 and id < 10000;
select * from table_name where id >= 10000 and id < 20000;
select * from table_name where id >= 20000 and id < 30000; 
...
```

The problem is if the `id size number` big, mysql may take it as a `Full table scan`.

**Update1**: Slow query log

```
# Query_time: 600.632844  Lock_time: 0.000071 Rows_sent: 624  Rows_examined: 236584
SELECT `id`, ... FROM `table_name` WHERE ( `id` >= 647121 ) AND ( `id` <= 765101 );
```

**Update2**: Explain

```
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table_name | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    1 | Using where |
```

**Update3**: Mysql Version

```
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.1.46-log | 
+------------+
```

And if we send 3 querys like that at the same time, the server's query time is so long and we could not bear.

So, is it possible to do split query in parallel? If not, why Sqoop do like this? thx.

Comment: Just create multiple connections to the database and issue the queries in the question.

Comment: I assume id is a primary key or has index. Have you tried `EXPLAIN` to check whether it is really doing a table scan?

Comment: @HongTat Yes `id` is the primary key. I will show the slow query log in mysql.

Comment: So that explain is for `where id >= 1 and id < 10000` query? What if you reduce the upper bound to `100`?

Comment: @zerkms Seems not a full table scan. But why so slow?

Comment: @hahakubile: what is the table schema?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not using any keys. Are you using a rather old MySQL version?

The `EXPLAIN` should be similar to this:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  table_name  range   PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   NULL    5926    Using index condition
```

Comment: sorry, I have made a misstake about the explain result. alreay Updated.